# Calcium carbonate and hydrogen peroxide reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

In application of hydrogen peroxide to soil and groundwater to remediate petroleum contamination, how will the naturally occurring limestone react with the peroxide, thereby reducing the effectiveness of the application.  Would calcium peroxide be more suitable.

Comment: [Calcium peroxide](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_peroxide) is produced when hydrogen peroxide reacts with calcium hydroxide and not calcium carbonate.

Answer (score 3):

The effect of aqueous hydrogen peroxide on natural limestone has been examined in a different context (removal of moss and algae from the walls of frequently visited and therefore illuminated show-caves).

The results were published in *Environ Pollut.*, **2003**, *122*, 417-422 ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12547531)).

The authors exposed etatons of limestone to various aqueous solutions for about four months and examined possible damages using a scanning electron microscope. They found:

> Based on SEM study, the polished surfaces of the carbonate etalons did not show any changes after 135-day exposure to rainwater, 15% peroxide, and 30% peroxide, respectively. No etched pits or any other visible
>   effects of dissolution [...] were detected.